# Gibberish phoneme dialog like in Animal Crossing

Tags: dialogue, max-msp, programming, web

Animal Crossing has an interesting style ([see video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KcTf6CCHr-w)) of creating these meaningless phonemes to simulate conversation. They even have different sounds for different characters, thus giving them personality.

I would like to create these programmatically (at first in Max/MSP and then later port it to the browser in some way). I'm not entirely clear however on my options, how to do this, etc.

So far I have a list of tones, and with a simple envelope, every character is assigned a different tone based on its value, that tone then plays in one of the voices via a square wave.

How would I improve this method?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, while containing audio elements, it's asking about procedural gereation and would be a better fit for a programming site.

Comment: In my opinion the procedural generation bit is almost trivial as opposed to sound engineering/synthesis part, which is why I posted it here.

Comment: I think it is off topic because "how would I improve this" is entirely opinion based. You could improve it any way you like